# Create a record based on elements in another array in one line

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of required items and wanted to create a record based off of the elements in that array. Each key in the required array will have an empty array in the exist record. Basically, I want to do the code below in one line:

```
const required = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
const exist: Record<string, string[]> = {};
required.forEach((key) => this.exist[key] = []);
```

The exist record will look like this:

```
exist = {
    'firstName': [],
    'lastName': []
}
```

I'm sort of new to typescript and wanted to see if this is possible.

Comment: Kind of curious why `'firstName': [],` and why not just a string? Does this ( for example if it were a "person") referenced have multiple first names?

Comment: I was hiding sensitive information from my actual code. firstName was the first thing that came to mind when I typed that question out. I know it doesn't make sense haha

Comment: Ah I see; this is a polycephaly of some sort like for your box of hydra's :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const required = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
const exist = Object.fromEntries(required.map(key => [key, []]));
console.log(exist);
```